# Ocorrência de um dígito num número inteiro usando Python

Tags: python, algoritmo

Dado um número inteiro n, n > 0, e um dígito d, 0 <= d <= 9, determinar quantas vezes d ocorre em n.

```
def main():
ocorrencia = 0
numeroReal = int(input("Digite um número inteiro positivo:\n"))
numero = numeroReal
digito = int(input("Digite um dígito para que analisemos sua ocorrência no número anteriormente digitado:\n"))
while numero != 0:
    if (numero % 10 == digito):
        ocorrencia += 1
        numero = numero//10
print("O dígito ", digito, "ocorre", ocorrencia, "vezes no número", numeroReal)
main()
```

O programa funciona quando insiro números simples, mas quando insiro 23111432411 pra encontrar a ocorrência do 1, por exemplo, o programa fica calculando eternamente e não retorna nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código que faz pegar o próximo dígito, a divisão, está condicional, então só se entrar na contagem é que isso acontece

Não é que só ocorre em números grandes, ocorre em todos que exista um número a ser contado.

O cálculo usado para pegar o próximo dígito deve ser feito em todas passagens do laço, não apenas quando houver uma contagem.

```
def main():
    ocorrencia = 0
    numeroReal = int(input("Digite um número inteiro positivo:\n"))
    numero = numeroReal
    digito = int(input("Digite um dígito para que analisemos sua ocorrência no número anteriormente digitado:\n"))
    while numero != 0:
        if (numero % 10 == digito):
            ocorrencia += 1
        numero = numero // 10
    print("O dígito ", digito, "ocorre", ocorrencia, "vezes no número", numeroReal)
main()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/v2x1T7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vihrxcwr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/CountOccurrences.py).

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão de forma correta devemos atentar para duas coisas importantes do enunciado.

1. Os possíveis valores de `n` (n > 0);
2. Os possíveis valores de `d` (0 <= d <= 9).

Outra coisa é perceber que `n` sempre será um valor `inteiro`.

Diante destas observações podemos implementar o seguinte código...

```
def exibi_quantidade_digitos(num, dig):
    """
    Esta função exibe a quantidade de um determinado dígito encontrado em um número.
    :param num: número inteiro.
    :param dig: dígito que será contado.
    :return: quantidade do dígito verificado no número.
    """

    # Contando a quantidade do dígito informado:
    cont = 0
    for c in n:
        if c == d[0]:
            cont += 1
    print(f'\033[32mA quantidade de dígitos "{dig}" encontrada em "{num}" é: {cont}')


# Capturando e tratando o número digitado:
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite o número: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Capturando e tratando o dígito digitado:
while True:
    try:
        d = int(input('Digite o dígito que desejas contar: '))
        if (d < 0) or (d > 9):
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros entre "0" e "9"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

n = str(n)
d = str(d)
exibi_quantidade_digitos(n, d)
```

Veja o funcionamento do programa no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/khjsiili-solkarped).

Observe que neste programa implementei dois blocos de tratamento de erros e exceções. Restringindo a digitação errada do usuário.

Em seguida, o programa conta o `número de ocorrências` do referido dígito e, posteriormente exibi o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Agora que você conseguiu resolver de acordo com a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/461093/22000), dê uma olhada na solução abaixo, talvez ela sirva para complementar seus estudos.

Como a entrada do usuário sera em `texto`, seria mais fácil procurar um digito dentro de um texto do que converter a entrada para um `inteiro` e então realizar operações matemáticas para descobrir se o digito esta nesse valor inteiro, dito isso você poderia usar um `loop` para contar a quantidade de vezes que o digito aparece no texto que o usuário digitou ou usar a classe `Counter` da biblioteca nativa do python:

#### Usando um loop

```
def main():
  entrada_usuario = input("Digite um número inteiro positivo:\n")
  digito = input("Digite um dígito para que analisemos sua ocorrência no número anteriormente digitado:\n")

  ocorrencias = 0
  for numero in entrada_usuario:
    if digito == numero:
      ocorrencias += 1

  print("O dígito ", digito, "ocorre", ocorrencias, "vezes no número", entrada_usuario)
```

#### Usando a classe Counter do pacote collections

```
from collections import Counter

def main():
  entrada_usuario = input("Digite um número inteiro positivo:\n")
  digito = input("Digite um dígito para que analisemos sua ocorrência no número anteriormente digitado:\n")

  contador = Counter(entrada_usuario)
  # supondo que o conteúdo de "entrada_usuario" seja "98876"
  # o conteúdo de "contador" seria Counter({'9': 1, '8': 2, '7': 1, '6': 1})
  # note que a chave é o numero que o usuário digitou e o valor é a quantidade
  # de ocorrências desse digito

  # o método "get" retorna o 0 caso "digito" não seja encontrado em "contador"
  ocorrencias = contador.get(digito, 0)
  print("O dígito ", digito, "ocorre", ocorrencias, "vezes no número", entrada_usuario)
```